# Fast file copier with Samba support?

Tags: filesystem, samba, networking, file-sharing

I'm looking for a fast file manager for Ubuntu.

I need to copy a lot of files to Windows machine via Samba. Nautilus is so slow, that when I click on the directory I need to copy the screen just dims and takes forever to list the files.

Any recommendations, except compiling `mc` from source? Maybe some terminal command?

Comment: It sounds like you have network issues... at least with samba. Nautilus is only as slow as the protocol it's trying to execute on, it'll be just as slow through anything else.

Comment: @Martin It is slow on local drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mount the windows shares using smbfs (for instructions check http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/165), then just copy from the terminal using rsync.